# Why WildFly 21 logs prints exception stacktrace with datetime on each line?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, wildfly, filebeat

I am using default WildFly logging, server.log shows `stderr` with timestamp nanoseconds and at new line always. On the other hand each normal exception trace are always printed with out datetime, but on the first occurrence, e.g. below is what I want to have so I can tackle in ELK.

```
2023-06-14 12:23:12,319 ERROR [stderr] (pool-17-thread-1)   at 
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:734) 
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364) at 
 javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)   at 
 javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)   at 
 javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230) at 
 javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
```

However, WildFly logs prints as below: how to prevent printing as below format.

```
2023-06-14 12:23:12,319 ERROR [stderr] (pool-17-thread-1)   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:734)
2023-06-14 12:23:12,320 ERROR [stderr] (pool-17-thread-1)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
2023-06-14 12:23:12,321 ERROR [stderr] (pool-17-thread-1)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
2023-06-14 12:23:12,322 ERROR [stderr] (pool-17-thread-1)   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
2023-06-14 12:23:12,323 ERROR [stderr] (pool-17-thread-1)   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
2023-06-14 12:23:12,323 ERROR [stderr] (pool-17-thread-1)   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
```

Comment: This generally happens if something printed this to stderr (e.g. using `exception.printStackTrace()`, or some logging layer/library printing to stderr), and `System.err` itself is redirected to the 'normal' logging. It can also indicate there are multiple logging libraries in use in your project, and they are either not all configured correctly, or you must replace them (or enhance them) with some logging redirection dependency.